# How to extend this PDE?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $(M^n,g)$ and $(N^m,h)$ be Riemann manifolds without boundary of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively and $u:(M^n,g)\to (N^m,h)$ be a map satisfying the following PDE on $M^n\backslash\Sigma$ ($u$ is smooth on $M^n\backslash\Sigma$ )

$\Delta_gu+A(\nabla u,\nabla u)=f(x,u,\nabla u)$,

where $A$ denotes the second fundamental form of $N^m\subset \mathbb{R}^Q$ (by Nash's embedding theorem), $\Delta_g$ denotes the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $(M^n,g)$, $f$ is a smooth function defined on the whole $M^n$ with linear dependence on $\nabla u$  and $\Sigma$ is a $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}-$dimensional set (Here $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}$ denotes the $(n-2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $(M^n,g))$.

It is easy to check $u$ satisfies the weak formulation of this PDE, that is

$\int\nabla u\nabla\varphi+A(\nabla u,\nabla u)\varphi=\int f(x,u,\nabla u)\varphi$ on $M^n$,

if we take the test functions in $C_c^\infty(M^n\backslash\Sigma)$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ This PDE can extend across $\Sigma$ by a standard capacity argument such that $u$ satisfies the weak formulation of this PDE globally, i.e. we can allow the test functions $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(M^n)$. How to do it?

I guess the linearity may be crucial in such extension argument. Because this argument can't be applied to a non-linear PDE, called "stationary" PDE for weakly harmonic maps. Otherwise, it will contradict with a well-known fact: the limit map of a weakly converging $($in sobolev space $W^{1,2}(M^n,N^m))$ squence of stationary harmonic maps may not be stationary. But it is still a weakly harmonic map (This is a direct corollary of this question).